# Spring boot AMQP, sending message to queue in multiple hosts env

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I want to have multiple senders to send the message to prd/tst/dev in one go from one application.

The rabbitmq properties if set in application.properties are configured for one env. only.

How to have different sender send to different env. ?

Comment: I think you should take a look into RabbitMQ Federation solution: https://www.rabbitmq.com/federation.html

Comment: The question is more of spring-boot configuration nature as how to have multiple parallel configuration for senders.

Comment: Well, no choice: do that manually. Spring Boot isn't aimed to fix all the problems. It is only some configuration on convention starter. Everything rest is a logic of your application.